# Best way of posting values in a form which contains a single quote

Tags: html, forms

When I submit a value which contains an apostrophe, 2 apostrophes are returned.

So if O'rourke is entered into the text box when I print $_POST['surname'] I see O''Rourke.

This is the code

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
<form method=post action=<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>>
Surname<input type='text' name='surname' value='' />
<input type='submit' value='Register'>
</form>
```

What is the best way of stopping this. Obviously I can do a string replace but is there a better way? For instance is there a way of stopping this in the form rather than in the action.

Please note this has nothing to do with MySQL.

Please also note that passing a value outputed by htmlentities still results in O''Rourke being printed out. The code I used is shown below.

```
<form method=post action=<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>>
Surname<input type='text' name='surname' value="<?php echo htmlentities("O'Rourke") ?>"/>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

I am not sure how this would help anyway when a user enters text into the text box and hits submit. Sorry if I have misunderstood how to use htmlentities.

Comment: Doesn't happen on my local Windows server. It only happens when I use a Linux server hosted remotely.

Comment: have a look into `htmlentities` function of php: [http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem With O'Rourke i get `Array ( [surname] => O'rourke )` on my server.

Comment: Bloody double quotes go away when I switch magic quotes off using .htaccess!